# In Meteor, how do I know on the client-side when the server-side operation is done?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I know Meteor does client-side caching of the database for better effective performance. In the client-side Meteor method call, is there any way to know when the *server-side* database operation *actually* finishes (or if it actually failed)?  Are there events I can hook into to get notification when the full remote procedure call finishes? Is there some way to use `subscribe()` to know when this particular call "really" finishes?

For example, from the [simple-todos tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/update-and-remove), is there a way to get notification when the server-side deleteTask implementation is completely done (i.e. the server-side database has been updated successfully)?

```
Template.task.events({
  "click .delete": function () {
    Meteor.call("deleteTask", this._id);
  },
});
```

I know Meteor intentionally hides the server processing delay, but I'm curious about the net operation performance of the Meteor methods I'm writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include a callback with your [Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call). The callback will be run after the server has completed processing the request.

```
Template.task.events({
  'click .delete': function () {
    Meteor.call('deleteTask', this._id, function(err, result){
      if (err){
        // an error was thrown
      } else {
        // everything worked!
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - didn't realize it was that simple!